# PDFファイルのパスワードを自動入力するプログラム

Tags: java, pdf

現在Javaを使ってPDFファイルのパスワードを総当たりで解析するプログラムを作成しています。

半角英数字の組み合わせをn文字分出力するコードは出来たのですが、どのようにファイルのパスワードを自動入力させるかわかりません。

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Analysis{

    static void recursive_increment(int digit,String[] ans,String[] str){
        if ( digit == 0 ){
                for(int i = 0; i < ans.length;i++){
                    System.out.print(ans[i]);
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
        }else{
            for (int i = 0; i < 62 ;i++) {
            ans[digit-1] = str[i];
            recursive_increment(digit-1,ans,str);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("何桁の解析をしますか？");
        int num = scn.nextInt();

        String str[] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r",
                            "s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K",
                            "L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
                            "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"};
        String ans[] = new String[num];

        int digit = num;
        recursive_increment(digit,ans,str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> どのようにパスワードを自動入力させるかわかりません。

`iText` という PDF 作成、変換ライブラリを使って、PDF に パスワード設定したり
パスワードを設定された PDF を パスワード無しのPDF に変換する事ができるようです。

https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-decrypt-a-pdf-document-with-the-owner-password